# How to save image in SQL image type column from picturebox without mentioning pics url?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, image, picturebox

I have a `picturebox` where custom image is drawn when mouse button is pressed now i want to save that image in SQL's `image type column` .

I did search for saving but theres nothing for saving a pic from picturebox to sql image type column without url .

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601858/insert-picturebox-image-into-sql-server-database

Comment: `ntext `, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084590/how-to-load-image-from-sql-server-into-picture-box). Tho you would have to save the picturebox image to a jpeg first.

```
byte[] image = File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\11.jpg");
```

**Edited:**

```
    //without saving the image to a physical file
    MemoryStream stream=new MemoryStream();

pictureBox1.Image.Save(stream,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

byte[] pic=stream.ToArray(); 


SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO imageTest (pic_id, pic) VALUES (1, @Image)", yourConnectionReference);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", image);
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to store directly from PictureBox? Not from physical path?

Comment: Yes you can. Try this:


`MemoryStream stream=new MemoryStream();            pictureBox1.Image.Save(stream,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
[] pic=stream.ToArray();

SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO imageTest (pic_id, pic) VALUES (1, @Image)", yourConnectionReference);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", image);
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`