# How to insert image to SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I am trying to insert image to the table [student] I have created in my Microsoft SQL Server.

[Table student](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPz2Z.jpg)

I am using the `FileUpload` to upload the image, but I have problem with the code because my code always executes the catch block. Please help

```
try
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-H7KQUT1;Initial Catalog=SAOS;Integrated Security=True";

        string strname = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/upload/") + strname);

        con.Open();

        string insertQuery = "insert into student (SID, Email, Contact, FName, LName, HomeAddress, Gender, DOB, Image) values (@SID, @Email, @Contact, @FName, @LName, @HomeAddress, @Gender, @DOB, @Image)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SID", TextBoxID.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBoxEmail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", TextBoxContact.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", TextBoxFName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", TextBoxLName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomeAddress", TextBoxHome.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", DropDownListGender.SelectedItem.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", TextBoxDOB.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", FileUpload1.ToString());

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = "Image Uploaded successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = "Plz upload the image!!!!";
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ex.Message");
}
```

Comment: Please update your `catch` block to be `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);` (no quotes) and include the full exception details in your question.

Comment: You need to add the [exception details](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/) to your question.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601858/insert-picturebox-image-into-sql-server-database

Answer (score 0):

if you store image in sql server as  blob or image format you should send is as byte array.

```
int imglength = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
byte[] bytearray = new byte[imglength];
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", bytearray);
```